# Filterable List With Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is a simple filterable list of names. Now when I actually filter with the input, I have to type 'Ad' or 'am' to get 'Adam'.  But how to make it so that I can get 'Adam' by anything like 'dm' or 'da'?

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('keyup', filterList);

function filterList() {

    let filterValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value.toUpperCase();

    let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

        if (li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {

            li[i].style.display = '';
        } else {

            li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `dm` should give you `Adam`? What is the logic?

Comment: I want it so that a combination of any of the consisting letters of a list name gets a match.

Comment: So `maa` should also match  `Adam`? What about `dd`, `dma`, `mmd`?

Comment: ma should but not maa as there are not 2 'a's in Adam. No for dd and mmd. Yes for dma.

Comment: There are two a's in Adam.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1eW3Oi6uoc

Comment: what I want is that. However I can't figure out what he did differently.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want fuzzy searching. There are a few libs you can use to accomplish that. Here's a few:

- https://github.com/bevacqua/fuzzysearch
- https://github.com/krisk/Fuse

Comment: This is what I want but I can't figure out what he did differently. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1eW3Oi6uoc

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by first determining how many of each distinct character you need to find, keyed by that character. Then for each such distinct character see if you can find it that many times in the target string, by using the second argument of `indexOf` (to avoid double counting).

With some other changes and optimisations, your code could look like this:

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', filterList);

function matches(charCounts, s) {
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    for (let [ch, count] of Object.entries(charCounts)) {
        for (let i = -1; count--; ) {
            i = s.indexOf(ch, i + 1);
            if (i < 0) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function filterList() {
    const filterValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value.toUpperCase(),
        anchors = document.querySelectorAll('li > a:first-child'),
        charCounts = filterValue.split('').reduce( (acc, ch) => {
            acc[ch] = (acc[ch] || 0) + 1;
            return acc;
        }, {} );
    for (const a of anchors) {
        a.parentNode.style.display = matches(charCounts, a.textContent) ? '' : 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput"><br>
<ul>
    <li><a>Adam</a></li>
    <li><a>Eve</a></li>
    <li><a>Abel</a></li>
    <li><a>Cain</a></li>
    <li><a>Seth</a></li>
</ul>
```